# Laravel - after composer update

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

when i run this command `php artisan list` or any command in cmd i found this error

[Command Error Capure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fam4Q.png)

and the code bellow of the file artisan

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';


$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);

$status = $kernel->handle(
    $input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput,
    new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput
);

$kernel->terminate($input, $status);

exit($status);
```

any one can help me !!